# Unable to deploy using Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1) tool

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

First time developing Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App.

I figured how to create the .appx file after some googling. But now I need to deploy it to multiple customer devices, didn't figure that yet. For the moment I'm trying to deploy it to my development device, but it keeps throwing this error (see attached image).

I only have the myApp_ARM.appx file on my AppPackages folder. I can't find or browse to %FOLDERID_SharedData%. I have no idea where to find this ARM_Optimized.appx file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reboot your phone, make sure there is no update pending. It should let you deploy into your phone.

Second, for deploying to multiple customer devices, use Hockeyapp (hockeyapp.net) to distribute the appx or use enterprise app feature.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks.
HockeyApp is a 3rd party tool, and not free, is it?

Comment: Its free for limited usage, backed by MSFT.